# iteration over two lists in EF notation

Tags: c#

I am using EF MVC.
In my model I have a User that I want to turn into a Student and I need to assign some fields to the Student. I am making a method to batch Users to Students and I need to assign some fields to the Student. This is what I am currently doing

```
            var students = db.Students.AsQueryable();
            var users = db.Users.Where(u => !students.Any(s => s.UserId == u.Id) ).ToList();//exclude current students from users

            Student[] filteredStudents = new Student[users.Count];
            var i = 0;

            foreach (var user in users)
            {
                filteredStudents[i] = (Student)user;
                filteredStudents[i].CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                filteredStudents[i].ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
                i++;
            }
            db.Students.AddRange(filteredStudents);
```

And in my Student class

```
        public static explicit operator Student(User user)
        {
            Student student = new Student() { UserId = user.Id, ApplicationUser = user };
            return student;
        }
```

I feel like there should be something more elegant that I am missing.
I have seen zips but I wanted something that resembles EF notation, like this pseudo code

```
var finalList = students.AssignMany(UserId = Id, this.User = User,  Users.Select(Id, User));
```

Is this possible?

Comment: `ConvertAll()` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Put the dates in the converter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using [ConvertAll()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) you can use your function that takes a user and returns a student and pass it as a parameter.  The `ConvertAll` function will then return a list of Students.

```
var users = db.Users.Where(u => !students.Any(s => s.UserId == u.Id) ).ToList();//exclude current students from users

var newStudents = users.ConvertAll(new Converter<User, Student>(UserToStudent));  //newStudents will contain the converted users, to do with what you want.


......snip.....

function static Student UserToStudent(User toConvert){
    Student student = new Student(){UserId = toConvert.Id, ApplicationUser = toConvert, CreatedDate = DateTime.Now, ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now};
    return student;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to iterate over 2 Lists and use info from both to create a new List of objects?

Comment: Something like Converter<TInput, TInput, TOutput>?

Comment: sounds like you just want to union two lists together first.  `list1.concat(list2).convertAll(...)`  are the lists of different types?

Comment: Yes. I have a list of students and a list of courses I want to register them which creates a list of StudentCourses.